# Expo OTA updates android app when I run "exp build:ios"

Tags: react-native, expo

When running exp build:ios to perform an OTA update to my app, I noticed that my android app on the Google Play Store was updated with the changes that I was only looking to go out to my iOS app. I’m just looking for a quick explanation to this and how I can do specific OTA updates for iOS and Android.